# Trouble with Permissions using groups

Tags: 2010, permissions, sharepoint-server, groups, folder

So, here is the thing:
I'm using sharepoint server 2010
and i have a few groups that I created.

I have a library that have some folders on it, each folder named after each group I created.
And each folder also contains some .docx files.

Each file have on its permissions, some of the groups I created.

I want to know if its possible to add a group or remove a group from each item permissions.
For example: I want to make it so that on folder Group1 file3, nobody on Group2 can see this file there anymore, but will be viseble for the other groups.

Is it possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I wouldn't recommend breaking inheritance at the document level for all your libraries, this is possible. Just like you have created groups for each folder. You would want to take that a step further and create a permissions group at the file level.

For Example

[image]